# Ensure focus stays on menu after closing dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

I am using @material-ui with react. I've got the following problem:

With the keyboard, open the context menu, select "Assignee details" or "Requester details"

Close the dialog. When you tab again, the focus is now back at the top of the page, it should stay on the menu. How can I achieve this behavior?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-breeze-s4mkez?file=/src/Test.js

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current focused element (you can get it with document.activeElement) and after closing the menu, set focus to the desired element with element.focus()